# Loading data using external table and creating a log file with rejected records with reasons

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I want to know what's the way to create a log file which will contain the rejected records with the reason behind it.

Suppose for example

```
**EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,SALARY,MANAGER_ID**

100,Steven,King,24000,NULL

101,Neena,Kochhar,35000,100
```

I want to reject those reocrds where an `employee salary is greater than his/her manager's`.  so  record with `employee_id 101` will be rejected.
How can I create a log file that will contain information like

```
101,Neena,Kochhar,Salary can't be greater than manager's,100
```

Please guide me.. I have already created the scripts necessary to load the data into external table..

Answer (score 1):

One way to create a log file is to use the UTL_FILE package to open a log file, write whatever you want, and close the log file. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCESS_RECORDS IS
  fErr_log  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  fErr_log := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(SOME_DIRECTORY_OBJECT, 'your_filename_here.log', 'w');

  FOR eachRecord IN (SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE)
  LOOP
    IF eachRecord.SOME_FIELD NOT IN ('LIST', 'OF', 'VALID', 'VALUES') THEN
      -- Write error log entry

      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fErr_log,
                        eachRecord.KEY || ',' ||
                        eachRecord.FIRSTNAME || ',' ||
                        eachRecord.LASTNAME  || ',' ||
                        'SOME_FIELD not in list of valid values');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fErr_log);
END PROCESS_RECORDS;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and post my result